# App was not optimized to support the device screen size or resolution

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, screen-resolution, ios-autolayout

My IOS Application was Rejected Due to App was not optimized to support the device screen size or resolution.
How can I resolve it? Can Anyone Help me Please.
ipad Pro Screen View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnYvW.jpg
IPhone X Screen View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tHDy.jpg

Comment: Is the screenshot apple attached to you? Have you tried run your app on other different devices like iphone 5,iphone6,iphone 6 plus...?

Comment: iphone 5s - https://imgur.com/GRE1fTG Iphone 6s plus https://imgur.com/OBzYzuv

Comment: Did Apple specify which device is not optimized to support the device screen size or resolution? I think Apple should tell you some more detailed information.  Or any attached screenshot?

Comment: this is a screenshot https://imgur.com/Bh4eahf

Comment: You can leave a message there to ask Apple which page or which device not optimized to support the device screen size or resolution?

Comment: they attached 2 screenshots https://imgur.com/tvWNrqW and https://imgur.com/Fs1rM5K and how  can i improve speed of responding

Comment: Seems apple not satisfy with your design? You should improve it. For example, change the head icon to circle? And the logo icon? the notification red badeg part? This is part of my thinking, I don't know what Apple thought.
 To improve speed of responding, you should ask your server side to improve the response speed.

Comment: okay thats fine, Regarding Screen Size by any chance for Correct that ?Can u help me please.

Comment: You can open new thread and post your code there to ask for help. Or update your question here to describe the problem you are meeting and related codes. You can have a look at [designer-auto-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout)